# How to join 3 numpy csr sparse matrix into 1 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, data-science

I have 3 numpy csr matrixes a, b, c of shape 
(69918, 7559) 
(17480, 7559) 
(21850, 7559)

these are the return of numpy.hstack((some matrices ....)).to_csr()

I want to join them and convert them into shape 
(69918+17480+21850, 7559)

How should I do it.
I tried numpy.vstack function but that converts it into (3, 1) shape

Comment: sparse.vstack or hstack

Comment: I previously tried numpy.vstack that gives error. But scipy.sparse.vstack solves our problem.

Comment: The numpy functions don't know anything about sparse matrices.  They just wrap each matrix in a `np.array(a)`, which as you'll see makes a 0d object dtype array.  `a.toarray()` is the correct way to make a dense array.  `sparse.vstack` takes an entirely different approach to joining sparse matrices.